# How do I check for a "4 in a row" with a 2d array? Note that I'm not using "numpy" as I am extremely new to coding

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I've got a connect 4 game using turtles. I've got a 2d array with 6 rows of 7. I don't know how to make a list check for 4 in a row. It's connect four so it needs to check for diagonally, horizontally, and vertically.
This is my list:

```
c4board = [[0]*7 for _ in range(6)]
```

I have a turtle over each column that when clicked will insert an item into the list via this:

```
def x2click(x,y):
  global currentturn
  global x2rowcor
  checker = trtl.Turtle()
  checker.ht()
  checker.shape("circle")
  checker.turtlesize(2)
  checker.color(currentturn)
  checker.penup()
  checker.goto(-80, x2rowcor)
  checker.st()
  x2rowcor += 40
  listxcor2 = ((x2rowcor+80)/40)-1
  print(listxcor2)
  checkerplaced()
  if c4board[5][1] == 0:
    c4board[5][1] = onetwo
    print(c4board)
  elif c4board[4][1] == 0:
    c4board[4][1] = onetwo
    print(c4board)
  elif c4board[3][1] == 0:
    c4board[3][1] = onetwo
    print(c4board)
  elif c4board[2][1] == 0:
    c4board[2][1] = onetwo
    print(c4board)
  elif c4board[1][1] == 0:
    c4board[1][1] = onetwo
    print(c4board)
  elif c4board[0][1] == 0:
    c4board[0][1] = onetwo
    print(c4board)
  if x2rowcor > 120:
    c2.ht()
    x2.ht()
```

I have tried to check for the turtle colors instead but found that to be a dead end.

I have tried to use Numpy but as I said I'm somewhat new to coding (I've only been doing python for a few months) Numpy was quite confusing to me, and I couldnt figure out how to get it to work.

If there isn't a way to do it without Numpy, please explain it to me like you would a 10 year old.

If you want my full 500+ lines of code, you can ask but i didnt want to put all of that in my question.

Comment: I've not read the full question but `c4board = [[0]*7 for _ in range(6)]` is going to cause you trouble, use `c4board = [[0 for _ in range (7)] for _ in range(6)]` instead

Comment: @mozway while that is good general advice, it wouldn't cause any issues in this specific case afaik because ints are immutable so `[0] * 7` creates a list of 7 separate integers.

Comment: @Pranav yes it was just a general comment, good habit to avoid this ;)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't fear `numpy` it is a very handy tool. To install it simply use `pip install numpy` from the command line in the same invironment you are using python.

---

Having numpy at hand the conditions I use are `1` for `player 1` and `2` for `player 2`. Now we can navigate through every `4x4` subfield of the game board to check for "four in a row of `1` or `2`"

```
# Import numpy to your script via this statement at the top of the file.
import numpy as np


def check_victory(board: np.array) -> int:
    """
    Navigating through all 4x4 subfields and check for victory condition
    of either player. 
    :returns: 1 or 2 of player 1 or 2 has won, 0 otherwise.
    """
    for row in range(7 - 4):
        for col in range(8 - 4):
            v = check_subfield(board[row:row + 4, col:col + 4])
            if v > 0:
                return v
    return 0


def check_subfield(field: np.array) -> int:
    # check diagonal.
    v = same_number(np.diagonal(field))
    if v > 0:
        return v
    for i in range(4):
        # check column
        v = same_number(field[i, :])
        if v > 0:
            return v
        # check row
        v = same_number(field[:, i])
        if v > 0:
            return v
    return 0

def same_number(values: list) -> int:
    return int((values == values[0]).all() * values[0])
```

All methods will return as soon as a victory condition is met to avoid superflous checks. There are more sophisticated ways to check this (see [rolling windows](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html), etc.), but this version should be somewhat beginner friendly with a not too high level of abstraction and library use. I hope this gives you a readable and understandable example.

---

Now, with this set of methods at hand, we can easily test this:

```
# We can create an empty 6x7 game board (zeros everywhere) 
# by using the `numpy.zeros` method with the desired shape:
c4board = np.zeros((6, 7))
print(check_victory(c4board))
# Out[0] = 0

c4board[2, 1] = 1
c4board[2, 2] = 1
c4board[2, 3] = 1
c4board[2, 4] = 1
print(check_victory(c4board))
# Out[1] = 1

c4board = np.zeros((6, 7))
c4board[2, 1] = 1
c4board[2, 2] = 1
c4board[2, 4] = 1
c4board[5, 3] = 2
c4board[5, 4] = 2
c4board[5, 5] = 2
c4board[5, 6] = 2
print(check_victory(c4board))
# Out[2] = 2

c4board = np.zeros((6, 7))
c4board[2, 2] = 1
c4board[3, 3] = 1
c4board[4, 4] = 1
c4board[5, 5] = 1
c4board[5, 4] = 2
print(check_victory(c4board))
# Out[3] = 1
```

---

Ok, and if you insist to do it without `numpy`: here you go:
(I really recommend getting used to numpy, though)

```
def check_victory(board: list) -> int:
    for row in range(7 - 4):
        for col in range(8 - 4):
            # This part is now much more effort
            sub_field = [[board[i][j] for i in range(row, row+4)] for j in range(col, col+4)]
            v = check_subfield(sub_field)
            if v > 0:
                return v
    return 0


def check_subfield(field: list) -> int:
    # Note the change in syntax and list construction.
    # check diag.
    v = same_number([field[i][i] for i in range(4)])
    if v > 0:
        return v
    for i in range(4):
        # check row
        v = same_number(field[i])
        if v > 0:
            return v
        # check column
        v = same_number([field[j][i] for j in range(4)])
        if v > 0:
            return v
    return 0


def same_number(values: list) -> int:
    if all(v == 1 for v in values):
        return 1
    if all(v == 2 for v in values):
        return 2
    return 0
```

This cann be as easily checked as above

```
c4board = [[0 for _ in range(7)] for _ in range(6)]
c4board[2][2] = 1
c4board[3][3] = 1
c4board[4][4] = 1
c4board[5][5] = 1
c4board[5][4] = 2
print(check_victory(c4board))
# Out[4] = 1
```

Comment: It's very weird to use. numpy _only_ for slicing arrays. You can slice lists of lists in a similar way. The entire point of numpy is that it speeds up _array operations_, so you don't need to loop over the array to do things with it.

Comment: For example: `field[i, :]` is a numpy array (not a list), so `same_number` just needs to return `(values == values[0]).all() * values[0]` instead of all those loops and `if` statements.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi you're right. Maybe I overdid it with the 'no numpy but numpy' solution. I reflected your comment in the latest edit.

Comment: I got the array to update using numpy but the code you sent for checking victories doesn't seem to work. But maybe I did it wrong. I'm going to edit the question and just send my whole code if i cant figure it out.

Comment: @CooperBayliff "doesn't seem to Work" ist nothing I can debug. What ist the Error?

Comment: I did it wrong and the code you sent does in fact work. Thank you for your help :D